# Is RAID-0 faster than Windows Striped disk?

Tags: ssd, raid

I have two Intel SSD drives and a Gigabyte GA-880GA-UD3H motherboard.  I'd like to maximize performance by using RAID-0.  Windows makes it easy to configure striped disks, but will that perform as well as if I had configured RAID-0 in the BIOS?

Answer (score 2):

Any task you can unload from higher level software to lover level software or hardware usually comes with better performance. So if you unload the task of RAID management from Windows to your BIOS and/or hardware RAID controller, you should gain performance and stability. However, I do not think that you will be able to notice any difference. Having 2 SSDs is already a huge speedup from regular harddisks.

Comment: However, with cheap motherboards there is not necessarily more performance than in CPU. It's not always good idea to unload tasks to hardware RAID controller. Especially with high-performance disks.